# Issues with extracting data from a list then using them together in separate data (part of online course)

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to describe my issue.

For an online python course I'm following there's an exercise I can't figure out. (raise NotImplementedError() refers to lines I need to input code).

The line of code `station_years = 2019 - station_start_years[selected_station]` is what I'm stuck on. I'm aiming for the list "station_start_years" to chose its value based on my selected_station value, which is based on station_names.

`num = int(input('select a station: '))` was inserted by me so may be wrong.

Thanks for any help, I've read through the exercises but am lost.

## Read-only code cell

`station_names = ['Harmaja', 'Kaisaniemi', 'Kaivopuisto', 'Kumpula', 'lighthouse', 'Malmi airfield', 'Suomenlinna aaltopoiju', 'Vuosaari harbour']`

## Read-only code cell

`station_start_years = [1989, 1844, 1904, 2005, 2003, 1937, 2016, 2012]`

Below we can define the selected station:
 #raise NotImplementedError()

`num = int(input('select a station: '))`

`selected_station = station_names[num]`

Next we find the location of the selected station in the list of station names:

## Read-only code cell

`station_index = station_names.index(selected_station)`

Now we can calculate the years the station has been operational:

## YOUR CODE HERE

raise NotImplementedError()

​

`station_years = 2019 - station_start_years[selected_station]`

Now, we can print the station name and number of years of operation to the screen.
A sample print statement on screen is `'The Helsinki Harmaja station has been operational for 30 years.'` The print statements should work for all listed stations only by modifying the `selected_station` -variable that is defined earlier in this problem.

## YOUR CODE HERE

`raise NotImplementedError()`

```
 str(station_years)+ " years.

print(print_statement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the index of `selected_station` in `station_names` but then you use `selected_station` (which is the **name** of the station) to index your `station_start_years` list. You should be using `station_index` there:

```
station_index = station_names.index(selected_station)
station_years = 2019 - station_start_years[station_index]
```

(BTW, it is no longer year 2019…)

Comment: Thank you! I was following the course which began September 2019 and like to keep to the structure :)